# Asp.net: Can we use MasterPage's viewstate in ContentPage?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, master-pages

Asp.net: Can we use MasterPage's viewstate in ContentPage ?

Answer (score 0):

From a Content Page you can refer to a MasterPage through the `Master` Property.  Create a Property on the Master Page that uses its getter and setter to store its value in ViewState, like so:

```
string MyProperty
{
  get { return ViewState["MyProperty"] as string; }
  set { ViewState["MyProperty"] = value; }
}
```

Obviously you could make that code safer by testing for nulls and what-not...

Here's the important bit: **Viewstate elements are only accessible from the controls that added them** so you need to refer back up the tree.

You can also strongly type the `Master` property on `Page` by using the `<%@ MasterType %>` directive in your ASPX file, thusly:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/SourcePage.master"" %>
```

HTH.